# HSRP - How do I know the hostname of the standby router

Tags: switch, hsrp

How do I know the hostname of the standby router if I don't have a topology drawing?

'''

```
Vlan190 - Group 0
  State is Active
    2 state changes, last state change 1w5d
  Virtual IP address is 172.16.50.254
  Active virtual MAC address is 0000.0c07.ac00 (MAC In Use)
    Local virtual MAC address is 0000.0c07.ac00 (v1 default)
  Hello time 3 sec, hold time 10 sec
    Next hello sent in 0.704 secs
  Preemption enabled
  Active router is local
  Standby router is unknown
  Priority 110 (configured 110)
  Group name is "hsrp-Vl190-0" (default)
```

'''

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  You don't.

The HSRP protocol is a layer-2 protocol, so IP addresses or hostnames are irrelevant.

This is one of the thousand reasons why good network documentation is important.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Network documentation is very important and makes troubleshooting a lot easier. I don't even know on which interface is the secondary router connected. There is no other way how to find the secondary router?

Comment: There may be a way to see the standby MAC address (I don't know the command off the top of my head.  If you have that, you can look in the MAC address table or ARP cache.